# Merge line by line in vimdiff?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

while giving the `dp` command in vimdiff it replaces the entire block(2 lines) with pink colour on  left hand side file to right hand side file.

In that block if i want to merge only the second line. First line should not be Merged.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the one line that you need to be overwritten:

```
:.diffget
```

Or just:

```
:.diffg
```

If you want to re-calculate the "pink areas" now:

```
:diffu
```

If the line is absent, it's best to hit `O` to add an empty line and then do a  `:.diffg`

Just adding it as an answer, so people can vote on it. For me it works better (when bound to a key combo) than `do` or `dp`.

Comment: similarly one could just get away w/ `:.diffput`

Answer (score 4):

You can just copy the part of the code you want to copy over using:

1. Hit the `V` key and then select just the text you want to move; and then hit `yy` to yank it.
2. Press `CTRL+ww` to switch windows, and then move your cursor to the desired location
3. Finally, press `p` to paste it in the desired location.

Comment: @vinothcse2000: There is no direct command, you have to build a custom mapping / command, using the basic steps outlined here.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: what about `:diffput` in visual mode or with range `:.diffput`? Its results vary, but it does something reasonable in some cases.

Comment: @xaizek: As far as I can remember, it doesn't yield results you can depend upon (without further inspection). That's why I wrote such wrapper for myself a long time ago, too.

Comment: If one presses `yy` no `V` is ever needed in fact.